# Can I use email in OAuth response for linking to user account?

Tags: php, codeigniter, security, oauth-2.0

I am planning to allow users to login to my website using oAuth authentication. I have a doubt whether I can completly rely on the email returned from the response to link the users to actual user account in my website. Can there be any security issue with this?

Answer (score 1):

The most immediate, is that you must absolutely trust the oAuth provider. It might lie to you and take over your local user account.

For example, if the oAuth provider does not validate the user email, someone might register an account there with someone else's email, then login to your site taking over the local user account.

Also make absolutely sure you're using SSL.